# How to redirect from confirmation page back to page of form?

Tags: 8, webforms

Is it possible to have a form redirect the user after landing on the confirmation page back to the previous page (page of the form)?

Note: I'm using Webform for D8

Comment: By hook_form_alter we can redirect form submission.

Comment: no idea how to do that

Comment: Doesn't webform have an option that lets you enter a URL to redirect to when complete? The 7.x version did.

Comment: Kevin. unfortunately no. It does have an option to enter a URL where to redirect, but not to redirect after arriving on confirmation page

Answer (score 1):

```
I have written the code for d7 where the article node form once submitted it is redirected back to the form.
    It will help you for d8.
    /**
     * Defines hook_form_alter()
     */
    function demo_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
        if (strstr($form_id, 'article_node_form')) {
          $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'] = array('demo_form_submit');
        }
    }
    // custom submit handler for '_node_form'
    function demo_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
      // call default action
      node_form_submit($form, $form_state);
      $form_state['redirect'] = url('node/' . 'add' . '/article', array(
          'absolute' => TRUE
        )
      );

      $_GET['destination'] = $form_state['redirect'];
    }
```